# Compute pullback of a 1-form

Tags: differential-forms

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ be defined via

$$(s,t) \mapsto (\sin t, st^2, s^2-1)$$

Let $\omega$ be the $1$-form

$$\omega=dx + x \, dy+y^2 \, dz$$

I computed $f^*\omega$ to being (the pull back under $\omega$)

$$\cos t + 2t \sin t \, dt \,+2s^3t^6 \, ds$$

Did I compute it correctly? I dont think so, so I recomputed below:

I did

\begin{align}
f^*\omega&=f^*(dx+x \, dy+y^2\, dz)\\
&=d(\sin t)+\sin t \, d(st^2) + s^2t^4 \,d(s^2-1)\\
&=\cos t dt + \sin t(t^2 \,ds +2st\, dt) +2s^3t^4 \, ds\\
&= \cos t \,dt + t^2 \sin t \,ds + 2st \sin t \,dt +2s^3t^4 \,ds \\
&=(\cos t + 2st \sin t) \, dt + (t^2 \sin t + 2s^3t^4)\, ds
\end{align}

is THIS correct^?

Comment: How do you get the last term?

Comment: would you like to see my work @ArcticChar

Comment: oh I multiplied instead of adding

Comment: You are missing a $\sin t$ in the last line

Comment: you're right, edit made @ArcticChar

Comment: @ArcticChar is or correct now?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$